# Get event for new USB keyboard connected on Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, usb, xinput

Is there any event I can listen to when a new keyboard attaches in Python? I'd like to disable the internal laptop keyboard and run xmodmap for the new keyboard. My only idea right now is polling `xinput list` and then grep USB. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's years since I've done anything like this, so I don't have any code examples for you, but I think for the problem you're looking at, you should consider a udev rule.

This looks like a good resource for udev: https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux

If I remember correctly (It's a VERY long time since I made a custom udev rule; I might NOT remember correctly), one thing you could do is execute a python script when something's plugged in, and that something happens to be a USB keyboard.